# UITableViewを使ってチェックリストを作成したが、押してもチェックがつかない

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift5

#### 実現したいこと

XcodeでUITableViewを使ったチェックボックス付きのリストを作っています。
空欄のボックスとチェックのついたボックスの画像がcellが押されると変更されるようにしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
現状は、空欄のボックスは表示されますが、cellを押してもcellが選択されるだけで画像には変化がありません。何か解決法はありますか？

あと、できればセルを押した後選択が解除されるようにしたいです。

分かる方、お力添えよろしくお願いします。

#### ソースコード

リストに表示するデータはmodelファイルにあるdictionary`commonDictionary`から取ってきています。

```
import UIKit

class ShoppingTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var shoppingTableView: UITableView!
    
    var val = commonDictionary[key2021323]
    lazy var shopList: [[String:String]] = val![keyIngList] as! [[String:String]]
    var localDate = "hoge"
    
    var checked :UIImage = UIImage(named: "checked-checkbox--v1.png")!
    var unchecked :UIImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked-checkbox.png")!
    var ud = UserDefaults.standard
    var status = String()
    
    func updateData (_ selectedDate:String) {
        localDate = selectedDate
        self.val = commonDictionary[selectedDate]
        if val != nil {
            self.shopList = self.val![keyIngList] as! [[String:String]]
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shopList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let temp = shopList[indexPath.row]
        let ingname = temp[keyIngName]
        let ingq = temp[keyIngQ]
        if ingname != nil, ingq != nil {
            let labelString = ingname! + " : " + ingq!
            cell.textLabel!.text = labelString
            if (self.val![labelString] != nil) {
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "checked-checkbox--v1.png")
            } else {
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked-checkbox.png")
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            let cellText = cell.textLabel?.text
            if cell.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "checked-checkbox--v1.png") {
                self.val?.updateValue(false, forKey: cellText!)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked-checkbox.png")
            } else {
                self.val?.updateValue(true, forKey: cellText!)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "checked-checkbox--v1.png")
            }
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 56
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }
}
```

#### 開発環境

Swift5
Mac OS 11.2.2
Xcode 12.4

Comment: あなたのコードを試してみたのですが、チェックボックスの画像については「したい」に記載された通り、セルを選択するたびにチェックありなしがちゃんと切り替わっているように見えます。正直言って問題大有りのコードなので、現在質問文にある状態から少しでもいじったら動作は保証できません、と言うレベルではありますが、元の事象が再現できないと、確実なことは言えません。あなたが実際に試されているコードは一文字の変更もなしに、質問文にあるコードそのままでしょうか?

Comment: OOPerさん、コメントありがとうございます。本当にこのままです。今質問文にあるコードをそのままコピペしてみたのですが、先程と同様、うまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。だとしたら、何か他の設定の問題でしょうか。TableViewの **Selection** の状態はどうなっていますか? また delegate は正しく接続されていますか?

Comment: おっしゃる通り、delegateが接続されていませんでした！細かい部分まで注意するのは大事ですね！本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございました。ところでテストデータを30件ばかり用意してスクロールで消える範囲のセルのチェック状態をオンオフして動作を確認してみてください。本当に正しくチェック状態が保持されていますか?

Answer (score 0):

OOPerさんのコメントにあるように、delegateが接続されていませんでした。
非常に単純ですみません。